# Polars export with .write_parquet method is very slow

Tags: python-polars

I'm encountering a significant performance difference when exporting data to Parquet format using Polars compared to using PyArrow or Pandas. Below is the code snippet I'm using:

pandas version: 1.5.3

polars version: 0.20.9

OS: Windows

```
import polars as pl 
import pandas as pd
import time


data = {'id' : ['abcdefgh'*6] * 3_000_000,
        'code' : ['20032'] * 3_000_000}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
start = time.time()
df.write_parquet("try.parquet", use_pyarrow=False)
stop = time.time()
print(stop - start) # 13.43877625465393

start = time.time()
df.write_parquet("try.parquet", use_pyarrow=True)
stop = time.time()
print(stop - start) # 0.3627772331237793

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
start = time.time()
df.to_parquet("try.parquet")
stop = time.time()
print(stop - start) # 1.3980333805084229
```

Given that my original dataset closely resembles the synthetic data I created, which consists of long strings, I'm surprised to find that exporting to Parquet format with Polars takes significantly more time compared to using PyArrow or Pandas. Is this expected behavior? I expect Polars to have faster or similar export times.

Comment: With `0.20.11` I get `0.28, 0.49, 0.99` - Polars implemented a new String type in `0.20.6` so some things are still being ironed out I think e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14657

Comment: @Hericks that's not right.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor True - I misread the documentation. It's the C++ parquet vs Rust parquet implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I made a bug report and this will be fixed in the next version https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/14818

In this case, the default number of row groups are different between the two (I'm ignoring pandas because it just uses pyarrow).

Polars will write 11 row groups whereas pyarrow writes 3. That said, when I save each iteration of those it takes 0.538 sec and 0.176 for polars and pyarrow respectively.

That's not good but it's not 37x.

If we sync up the number of row groups to something like 500,000 rows per group then we get to 0.43 and 0.18.

If we look at the file sizes we get to a symptom. I get 835KB and 2.6KB files. The reason for that is pyarrow uses RLE_DICTIONARY encoding for strings whereas polars doesn't.

If I convert strings to categoricals before I save like this

```
start = time.time()
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(pl.String).cast(pl.Categorical)
    ).write_parquet(
        "trypl.parquet", 
        use_pyarrow=False, 
        row_group_size=500_000
        )
stop = time.time()
print(stop - start)
start = time.time()
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(pl.String).cast(pl.Categorical)
    ).write_parquet(
        "trypa.parquet",
        use_pyarrow=True,
        row_group_size=500_000
        )
stop = time.time()
print(stop - start)
```

then the save times go to 0.115 and 0.147 but the file sizes are still very divergent at 752KB and 2.7KB so apparently using RLE_DICTIONARY encoding is better than categoricals for sizing.

My guess is that you have a slow HD and so the much bigger file size is what's driving it to be so much slower for you.

Lastly, I think this is a bug (or if not a bug per se a limitation) related to the change of String types because polars used to do RLE_DICTIONARY encoding.